# Is there a way to replace just a specific character in a variable?

Tags: python, arcpy

Here is an example
    township = township[3].replace("0", "")
My goal being that if 10.0 is the current value for township I want to remove the zero after the . but not the one after the 1 with the end result being 10. The code above doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is 10.0 stored as a character or a numeric value?

Comment: This is a pure Python question so would be better asked at our sister site [**StackOverflow**](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: A string. township[3] = township[3].replace(".0","") would work if the user always enters 3 digits but sometimes the user just enters 10. I'm trying to get the program to work whether the user enters 10 or 10.0 and drop the . and zero if present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you are doing it to a string value, because you didn't mention rounding. The following code should work:

`township[3] = township[3].replace(".0","")`

Answer (score 3):

`township = township.rsplit('.', 1)[0]` should do what you want.

Comment: Yep that did exactly what I wanted. I'll post to stack overflow next time.